# Cocos2Dx - Create APK from Visual Studio

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I new with cocos2Dx and wanna create game for Android with using C++. I use proj.win32 and don't now how build .apk. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make entry of your `.cpp` files in `Android.mk` that exist in jni folder. Find jni folder inside `proj.android` project module.

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp
```

run this command on console

```
cocos deploy -s ./projects/MyGame -p andoird -m release
```

where **./projects/MyGame** is your project root folder **-m release** indicated you want .apk in release mode otherwise use debug

If want some Android related code then first import your project into eclipse then put your Android related code then deploy or even through eclipse you can deploy.